# Is it possible for $\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^2}$ to be complex at a turning point?

Tags: calculus

If it is possible, am I right in thinking that if it's -4-4i at that point, the point is a maximum? This question arose when i was attempting to answer the following question:

There are two poles (lets say poles A and B) $50$ feet apart and the poles are $15$ and $30$ feet tall. There is a wire which runs from the top of pole A to the ground, and then to the top of pole B so that two triangles are made. What is the minimum length of wire needed to set up this configuration?

Here is my answer:

Use pythagoras to express $l$ (the total length of rope in feet) in terms of $x$, where $x$ is the distance in feet from the base of the first pole to the point where the rope from the top of that pole touches the ground (which is $50 - x$ feet from the base of the other pole). Let l1 be the distance from top of the first pole to the point where the rope from the top of the first pole touches the ground and l2 the distance from there to the top of the second pole.

My calculations are as follows: $$l = l1 + l2,$$ $$l1 = ({15^2+x^2})^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ and $$l2 = ((50-x)^2+30^2)^\frac {1}{2}$$, so $$l = ({15^2+x^2})^{\frac{1}{2}} + ((50-x)^2+30^2)^\frac {1}{2}$$

$$\frac{dl}{dx} = \frac{1}{2} 2x(15^2+x^2)^\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(2x-100)(1600-100x+x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$ with turning points at $x = 0$ and $x = 50$.

$$\frac{d^{2}l}{dx^2} = -\frac{x}{2}(2x)(15^2+x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}} -\frac{1}{2}(15^2+x^2)^\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}x(-100+2x)+(1600-100x+x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}+50(2x-100)$$.

$$\frac{d^{2}l}{dx^2}(x = 50) = \frac{-50^2}{\sqrt{15^2+50^2}} -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{15^2+50^2}-0+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1600-5000+2500}}+0$$

The penultimate term is imaginary: is this ok, or have I made a mistake?

Comment: You should post the entire problem so that we can have better context. It's nearly impossible to answer your question as it stands.

Comment: I've started on posting the whole problem, but I've got to do something else now.

Comment: I presume you're trying to apply the 2nd derivative test. Is $-4-4i <0$?

Comment: No: it's a more complicated expression. The real part is negative, the imaginary part negative (unless I've made a mistake). The real part is larger in magnitude than the imaginary.

Comment: Sorry the imaginary part is positive (see edited question).

Comment: @bluesh34: Christian Blatter has presumably clarified matters for you, but to reiterate/emphasize, there's a sign error in your algebra: The radicand $1600-100x+x^2$ in your expression for $dl/dx$ should be $3400-100x+x^2$; you calculated $50^2-30^2$ instead of $50^2+30^2$. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly calculated
$$\ell(x)=(x^2+225)^{1/2}+(x^2-100x+3400)^{1/2}\qquad(0\leq x\leq50)\ .$$
Candidates for the minimum of $\ell(\cdot)$ are $x_1=0$, $x_2=50$, and the zeros of the derivative lying in the interval $[0,50]$. Therefore
we have to solve
$$\biggl(\ell'(x)=\biggr)\quad {x\over(x^2+225)^{1/2}}+{x-50\over(x^2-100x+3400)^{1/2}}=0\ .$$
Squaring gives
$${x^2\over x^2+225}={(50-x)^2\over x^2-100x+3400}\ ;$$
and this leads to a quadratic equation: 
$$0=x^2(x^2-100x+3400)-(50-x)^2(x^2+225)=675x^2+22500x-562500\ .$$
The  solutions are $-50$ and ${50\over3}$. We throw away $-50$ and add the point $x_3:={50\over3}$ to our candidate list. Comparing the values $\ell(x_k)$ $\ (1\leq k\leq 3)$ we find that the minimum is taken at $x_3={50\over3}$.

Note that it is absolutely superfluous to compute second derivatives here.

In closing I should  remark that there is a simple geometric solution to the problem: Stick the first pole 15 feet into the ground instead and connect the two ends by a straight line.

Comment: Not seeing the 'leads to a quadratic equation' part.

Comment: @bluesh34: See my edit.

Comment: Right you are- thanks